# Check if zshrc is being ran/sourced

Tags: zsh, debugging

I am running into an issue where I see command results in .zshrc being displayed twice; in trying to track down the issue I want to know how to check if .zshrc is being run (so I can tell whether it's a display issue or that .zshrc is actually ran twice).

So I am thinking some snippet that increment a counter each time .zshrc is sourced would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `.zshrc`:

```
echo "$(date) -- .zshrc executed" >> $HOME/.zshrc.log
```

You will then see a datestamp for every time the rc file is run, sourced, or otherwise executed in the file `.zshrd.log` in your home directory.

Comment: That works perfectly; and it shows me that the source is being run twice.  Not sure if I should ask a separate question on how to track down why it is running twice.  I checked the usual suspects mentioned here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175362/iterm2-runs-my-zshrc-twice but don't see .zshrc being sourced anywhere else.

Comment: That might indeed be worthy of a second question.  But you can also add more debug output than just `echo $(date)` - you could also add `pstree -pal` to the log.  You could also perhaps move the relevant scripting from `.zshrc` to `.zsh_profile` (presuming that's a thing) or modify your scripting to set an environment variable, and only run if it's not already set.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up switching to tmux because the issue only exists when I start a new screen session.  It had nothing to do with my .zshrc (tested by commenting out everything) and I removed various .profile & .zprofile etc.  It was also terminal independent.  I never figured out why it only happened in screen (tried to remove .screenrc etc).

Comment: I have the exact same situation - I moved all the zsh/bash/screen/xterm dotfiles except for my .zshrc. In my .zshrc, I have an include guard that should prevent it from executing its contents twice (including oh-my-zsh); I verified that it works. With xterm or screen, but no oh-my-zsh, it does exactly what I expect it to and there is no duplicate line. From there, in screen but not xterm, sourcing oh-my-zsh *does* introduce the problem! Does that give you any clues? I'm not sure what to test next.

Comment: Also - I think you meant to say it was emulator-independent, since you also said it only applied to screen.